# newtonsoft SerializeXmlNode trailing nulls

Tags: serialization, json.net

I am creating an XmlDoc in C# and using Newtonsoft to serialize to JSON.  It works, but I am getting a bunch of what appear to be "NUL"'s at the end of the JSON.  No idea why.  Anyone seen this before?

CODE:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = BuildTranslationXML(allTrans, applicationName, language);

// Convert the xml doc to json
// the conversion inserts \" instead of using a single quote, so we need to replace it
string charToReplace = "\"";
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc);

// json to a stream
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
tw.Write(jsonText);
tw.Flush();
tw.Close();

// output the stream as a file
string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.json", applicationName, language);
return File(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), "text/json", fileName);
```

The file is served up to the calling web page and the browser prompts the user to save the file.   When opening the file, it displays the correct JSON but also has all the trailing nulls.   See image below (hopefully the stackoverflow link works):

[file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjRXV.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetBuffer()` method returns the internal representation of the `MemoryStream`. Use `ToArray()` instead to get just the part of that internal array that has data `Newtonsoft` has put in there.

Comment: @ToddWilloughby - in that case, you might [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).